# git how to keep remote repository in sync while ignoring minor changes?

Tags: git

I have a localhost website and its live version on the internet. what i have is two `main` repositories one local and one remote and both are in sync and both track same files. the problem is that there have to be some minor differences between each like local one connect to database with different credentials and different google re-captcha keys and that's all the changes needed (exactly 3 or 4 files each differ by just one line). So is there a way i can keep both in sync, while each repository have its own version of database credentials and re-captcha keys and still make git track these files so in case i changed the keys i can still push them.

Comment: Consider not storing unique instance variables like database creds and captcha keys in git.

Comment: other than.... using branches? In general files where you have changes like these are _not_ tracked because it can be a little tricky to avoid changes on that file on one branch to trickle into the other (it's possible to avoid it.... but not _automagic_).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a .gitignore file to have git ignore files you don't want to be compared.

I would store keys in an environment variable file full of variables that allows you to configure them as needed in each environment. When you use the variables in the code, it will check the file for the value of those variables and you can have different configuration values in your different environments.